# How do I predict the structure of a nanoparticle with Calypso and Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: quantum-espresso, software-recommendations, geometry-optimization, structure, nanoparticles

I want to create a nanoparticle of CuO and predict it's structure. I've done unit cell relaxation with Quantum ESPRESSO. One tool to predict nanocluster structure is Calypso which is PSO-based. I'm using Quantum ESPRESSO with it. If anyone does [Calypso structure prediction](http://www.calypso.cn/documentation/), what are some ways for predicting nanocluster structure?
I want to use this nanostructure to calculate TDDFT and some other optical properties.

If there is any other way to predict a nanoparticle's structure (without Calypso) please let me know.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to make it more clear? What exactly are you looking to find/achieve?

Comment: I agree with Xivi76. What exactly do you mean by "run a nanoparticle structure" ? What precisely do you want to do? We will need to ***close*** the question if you cannot explain to us what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Is it understandable now? Please let me know.

Comment: It's better. I've made some edits now that I think I understand that the question is about how to predict a nanoparticle's structure, using Calypso with QE (or some completely different software). You might need to tell people what the reason is for your need to predict a nanoparticle structure, since the method may depend on what you need the calculation for. But let's see if there's someone that can help.

Comment: If you post on twitter and tag @StackMatter we can re-tweet for you. Also if you tag the authors of Quantum ESPRESSO / Calypso, it will help. It worked for this question: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/what-are-the-advantages-of-different-point-defects-calculation-tools As you see that the main developer of the software answered, and then someone also got their grad student to answer, both of them were not users of this site before, and both of them interacted with this tweet: https://twitter.com/StackMatter/status/1291159713636405249 Let us know when you do it!

Comment: Hi @ShafayetRahat, Can I know about the tool that you have used to make the nano structure?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As I mentioned here I've used calypso which is a PSO based package with Quantum Espresso.

Comment: @Nirajamoharana, Shafayet Rahat, we now have a Quantum ESPRESSO room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642/quantum-espresso Can you both please write "hello" in there so that in the future we remember about your interest in Quantum ESPRESSO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) Using CALYPSO with Quantum ESPRESSO**

> I want to create a nanoparticle of CuO and predict it's structure.
> I've done unit cell relaxation with Quantum ESPRESSO. One tool to
> predict nanocluster structure is Calypso which is PSO-based. I'm using
> Quantum ESPRESSO with it. If anyone does Calypso structure prediction,
> what are some ways for predicting nanocluster structure?

I've never used CALYPSO but you could follow this [tutorial](https://www.bragitoff.com/2019/03/nanocluster-global-optimization-using-calypso-and-quantum-espresso/)

**2) DFT on nanoclusters [The general stuff]:**

You can refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8TEpaW7RNc)

**3) TDDFT on nanoclusters [TurboTDDFT + Quantum ESPRESSO]:**

> I want to use this nanostructure to calculate TDDFT and some other
> optical properties.

Although I'm not an avid used of this software I've heard that this can be done via the **TurboTDDFT software** along with Quantum ESPRESSO.

- **[TurboTDDFT software:](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465511001512)** It is an implementation of the Liouville–Lanczos approach to linearized time-dependent density-functional theory, designed to simulate the optical spectra of molecular systems made of up to several hundred atoms.

Acquistion of the code as per comments in the paper:

> Additional comments: !!!!! The distribution file for this program is
> over 254 Mbytes and therefore is not delivered directly when download
> or E-mail is requested. Instead a html file giving details of how the
> program can be obtained is sent.